# Check if javascript object is inside an existing array

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to know how to check if an object still exists in an array

```
var a = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Jeffery" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Jimmy" }]
```

I'm trying to find if `Jeffery` is still in this array:

```
var obj = { "names": { "Jeffery": { "age": 43, "job": "Doctor" }, "Jimmy": { "age": 23, "job": "Developer" } } };
```

I've attempted to use this code which brings no luck. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
function contains(a, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: use typeof inside the iterator

Comment: please add the data of `obj` as well. small hint: you compare strict with an object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @NinaScholz check now.

Comment: your question is unclear, elaborate the relation between `a` and `obj` variables

Comment: `a` = array that I want to search with and `obj` is the array I want to search for

Comment: what do you expect as outcome? a single check of the first name only? all names?

Comment: I just want to return `true` or `false` to whether if `Jeffery` still exists in the `obj` array.

Comment: you do not have `'Jeffery'` as a paramter.

Comment: I need to set it as a parameter?

Comment: you given an array with two objects and an object with name as property with two properties. which would you like to test against?

Comment: Do you mind writing out an answer, you're making no sense to me.

Comment: for me, it is not clear, in which direction you like to check. a) with given string `Jeffery` in `a` or b) with given string `Jeffery` in `obj`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for a check of a property in an object.

> The **`in` operator** returns `true` if the specified property is in the specified object.

```js
function contains(name, obj) {
    return name in obj.names;
}

var obj = { names: { Jeffery: { age: 43, job: "Doctor" }, Jimmy: { age: 23, job: "Developer" } } };

console.log(contains('Jeffery', obj));
console.log(contains('Foo', obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the function `contains` you can check the desired name: `'Jeffery'` is in the the object and also in the array:

```js
var a = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Jeffery" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Jimmy" }],
    obj = { "names": { "Jeffery": { "age": 43, "job": "Doctor" }, "Jimmy": { "age": 23, "job": "Developer" } } };

function contains(name, a, obj) {
    return obj.names[name] && a.filter(o => o.name === name) ? true : false;
}

console.log(contains('Jeffery', a, obj));
console.log(contains('Jimmy', a, obj));
console.log(contains('Foo', a, obj));
```